# how to add all array's elements to one list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

with a 2 dimension array which looks like this one:

```
myarray = [['jacob','mary'],['jack','white'],['fantasy','clothes'],['heat','abc'],['edf','fgc']]
```

every elements is an array which has fixed length elements. how to become this one,

```
mylist = ['jacob','mary','jack','white','fantasy','clothes','heat','abc','edf','fgc']
```

here's my solve

```
mylist = []
for x in myarray:
   mylist.extend(x)
```

should be more simple i guess

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import chain
mylist = list(chain.from_iterable(myarray))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> myarray = [['jacob','mary'],['jack','white'],['fantasy','clothes'],['heat','abc'],['edf','fgc']]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(myarray))
['jacob', 'mary', 'jack', 'white', 'fantasy', 'clothes', 'heat', 'abc', 'edf', 'fgc']
```

However, [Haidro's `sum()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16316703) is faster for your shorter sample:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import withchain as f')
2.858742465992691
>>> timeit.timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import withsum as f')
1.6423718839942012
>>> timeit.timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import withlistcomp as f')
2.0854451240156777
```

but `itertools.chain` wins if the input gets larger:

```
>>> myarray *= 100
>>> timeit.timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import withchain as f', number=25000)
1.6583486960153095
>>> timeit.timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import withsum as f', number=25000)
23.100156371016055
>>> timeit.timeit('f()', 'from __main__ import withlistcomp as f', number=25000)
2.093297885992797
```

Comment: itertools for the win +1

Comment: Try the `sum` on a list of `100000` and see it die tragically!

Comment: @jamylak: Already did :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes you always seem to do that whenever I post a comment, I'm just not gonna bother next time :)

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> myarray = [['jacob','mary'],['jack','white'],['fantasy','clothes'],['heat','abc'],['edf','fgc']]
>>> sum(myarray,[])
['jacob', 'mary', 'jack', 'white', 'fantasy', 'clothes', 'heat', 'abc', 'edf', 'fgc']
```

Or

```
>>> [i for j in myarray for i in j]
['jacob', 'mary', 'jack', 'white', 'fantasy', 'clothes', 'heat', 'abc', 'edf', 'fgc']
```

Comment: i don't understand why can this line work?sum(myarray,[]),does [] imply this is a list addition?why not sum(myarray,list)?

Comment: @user2003548 Take a look at the python documentation about the sum function: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum . Pretty much, you iterate through `myarray` and it adds each element into the `start` parameter, here it being `[]`. So `[] + ['jacob','mary'] == ['jacob', 'mary']` and so on for every other element

Comment: @user2003548 I'll try explain it with another example. The default value of the second parameter is `0`. `sum([1,2,3], 0) == 6` (Which is what you would expect normally.) Now, doing `sum([1,2,3], 4)` equals `10`, because you're adding all the values of the list onto 4.